# WaitForFullGCApproach missed GC collections

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I am using the methods GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification, GC.WaitForFullGCApproach and GC.WaitForFullGCComplete to get informed by upcoming garbage collections. The GC.WaitForFullGCApproach is in a different thread which loops like this:

```
            while (!gcAbort)
            {
                GCNotificationStatus s = GC.WaitForFullGCApproach(10 * 60 * 1000);

                if (s == GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(GCState.Approaching, "GC is approaching ... ");
                    gcApproachNotificationCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (s == GCNotificationStatus.NotApplicable)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Concurrent garbage collection is enabled, or the time specified for the millisecondsTimeout parameter has expired and no garbage collection notification was obtained.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Unexpected GCNotificationStatus " + s);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (forceGCWhenApproaching)
                {
                    int maxGenCollectionCountBefore = GC.CollectionCount(GC.MaxGeneration);
                    Thread.Sleep(12000);
                    int maxGenCollectionCountAfter = GC.CollectionCount(GC.MaxGeneration);
                    if (maxGenCollectionCountBefore == maxGenCollectionCountAfter)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Inducing forced Gen {0} GC.. Collection count is {1}".FormatWith(GC.MaxGeneration, maxGenCollectionCountBefore));
                        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("GC was already triggered by the system! Old collection count was {0}; new count is {1}".FormatWith(maxGenCollectionCountBefore, maxGenCollectionCountAfter));
                    }
                }

                // Check for a notification of a completed collection.
                s = GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(10 * 60 * 1000);
                if (s == GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(GCState.Okay, "GC completed.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(GCState.Unknown, "Unexpected GCNotificationStatus: " + s);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

The problem is that I do not not get notified about all the garbage collections. So from time to time I would see something like this:

```
GC is approaching ... 

GC was already triggered by the system! Old collection count was 19; new count is 23

GC completed.

GC is approaching ...

GC was already triggered by the system! Old collection count was 33; new count is 37

GC completed.
```

which means that between collection count 23 and 33 I have missed all of them.

In my web.config file I have disabled concurrent GC:

```
  <runtime>
    <gcConcurrent enabled="false" />
  </runtime>
```

For the GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification I have tried multiple threshold values but with the same result.

Can you please tell me why I observe this behavior?

Comment: That 12 second sleep looks like a problem.

Comment: I do not think it is a problem. The difference which concerns me is the one from maxGenCollectionCountAfter of the previous run and the maxGenCollectionCountBefore of the current run. So if there is a difference between them in the same run, it is due to the 12 second delay, but if they are in different runs, they should be the same.

Comment: That sounds reasonable the way you say it but that's not what you coded.  You are complete deaf, dumb and blind for 12 seconds and will miss any collections that occur during that time.  Get rid of the Sleep().

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have removed the "if (forceGCWhenApproaching)" branch all together and I show the GC.CollectionCount(2) along with my gcApproachNotificationCount but they still drift apart.